# MySql Moving from development to production into a different user

Tags: mysql

I have a project that need to be moved to production (for the first time). The database includes few tens of tables and procedures/functions. They were all created under the ROOT user (yes, bad practice I know).

Now, I need to move the whole thing to production and obviously NOT under the MySQL ROOT user.

I thought to do the following, but am seeking expert opinion before I engage into it:

1. Get a backup using `mysqldump -u root -p -R MySB > dump.sql`,
2. Edit the file and replace all instances of `root` with `correct_user` (where **correct_user** would be the MySQL user owning all the tables and routines),
3. Create the same user within the production DB,
4. Restore from the dump file using `mysqldump -u correct_user -p -R MySB < dump.sql`.

Is my plan correct or is there a better (and more formal) way to do it?

Comment: It looks quite good.

Comment: Try doing the same on another reference system. If it works, you have your answer

Comment: Unfortunately @DaveyBoy, I don't have other **all purpose** system I can use to make this check. This is why I'm reaching out for an expert opinion.

Comment: If you have enough drive space, memory etc and the relevant access rights, spool up a virtual Linux machine in something like VirtualBox, install the DB on there and access it via the user you create it as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables in MySQL don't have **owner**. You do not have to worry about the user, that created them.

Procedure, functions, triggers, events and views have so called "**definer**". It is user, under which the code is executed. This one should be changed from **root**. Make sure the new user has enough privileges. He needs only privileges to run code inside routine and not more.

So your steps are correct. But the final loading(4) should be done as **root** or user with super privilege.

Comment: Did what intended (and described), and it all appears to be working as needed. Thanks @PavelKatiushyn!!